# Prove the existence of limit of certain sequences.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

**Problem:** Let $0<a_1<b_1$ and 
$$a_{n+1}=\sqrt{a_n\cdot b_n},b_{n+1}=\frac{a_n+b_n}{2}.$$ Prove that $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ converge to some limit.

**Attempt:** By induction and AM-GM, I can show that $0<a_n<b_n$ for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$.I am thinking maybe I can use Cantor intersection theorem at some point? Provided that I can show that $a_n \rightarrow$ and $b_n\downarrow$. But I am not sure if this is the right way to think about it.

Answer (score 1):

By induction on $n$ we have $a_n<a_{n+1}<b_{n+1}=(a_n+b_n)/2,$  so $0<b_{n+1}-a_{n+1}<(b_n-a_n)/2\leq 2^{-n}(b_1-a_1),$ so the increasing sequence $(a_n)_n$ and the decreasing sequence $(b_n)_n$ converge to the same value, which is called the Arithmetico- Geometric Mean of $a,b. $ (Or AG Mean for short).

Answer (score 0):

This is arithmetic geometric mean.

All you need is $ a_n < a_{n+1} $ and $ b_{n+1} < b_{n} $. With that the sequences are monotonic and bounded and therefore converges.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic%E2%80%93geometric_mean

Answer (score 0):

By using $0<a_n<b_n$ 
$$b_{n+1}=\frac{a_n+b_n}{2}≦b_n・・・≦b_1 $$
$$a_{n+1}=\sqrt{a_n\cdot b_n}≦b_n・・・≦b_1$$